# How can I Found what is causing crashing page in Mobile?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I have a problem:
Cart and checkout page in the mobile version: ***on scrolls page refreshed and suddenly crashed*** and in safari, I get this error: *a problem repeatedly occurred*.

**I checked the following ways** but I couldn't find what caused this problem:

- I enable WP_DEBUG and fix all errors.
- I check each single js file structure in online tools that check the
  structure of JS files.
- I create `wp-content/mu-plugins` and disable unnecessary plugins on these pages.
- I removed .css and .js files of the theme to see if this file caused
  this error.
- I checked the console in inspect mode. and there is no error there.

Would you please share your experience what else I should check to see the reason of the

Comment: Can you edit this post and add your own code?

Comment: Thanks Marcos for your attention to my question, code of which page should I add?

Comment: The code of the page where the error appears. Also, no more details about the error appear in the console?